# Datepicker Material Angular: How can i display full name of the month?

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

I use the Datepicker component (Material) in my Angular application.
In particularly i use the month view component (Here are an example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aaalqoapbenb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-start-view-example.ts)).
How can i display the full name of the month? I want a result like: January, February, etc.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Refer angular material example [here](https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.ts). It shows how to set date, month, year formats for angular datepicker.

Comment: Link error: Cannot GET /api/angular/v1

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated URL [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jejdvdkrbgl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.ts)

Answer (score 1):

you can import

```
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';
```

in your NgModule, declare your custom formats like this:

```
const MY_FORMATS  = {
    parse: { dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY' },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MM YYYY',
    }
}
```

And then provide them in the import section of your module like this:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ]
```

This will show the full month in the upper left corner of the datepicker.

I updated the plunkr example you provided [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnfacu?file=src/app/material-module.ts)

Unfortunately there is no way to further customize the dates shown in the datepicker. As you can see [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/9eeb4b5aa0473c0815a73bfe3c2ed6164d86a3b3/src/material/core/datetime/date-formats.ts) the `MatDateFormats` type only allows the customization of this 4 display properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment date formats to do that

```
// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

Full example

https://stackblitz.com/angular/jejdvdkrbgl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

Change ts file as follow

```
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL'
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-start-view-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-start-view-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-start-view-example.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerStartViewExample {
  startDate = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
}
```